# Are variable in aurelia custom attributes "static"

Tags: aurelia

Say I have a custom attribute in Aurelia and I put it on two different element.

If I have variable defined in the class called `clickWhen: Date;`

And if I set that in a method fired from the first element that has the custom attribute (ie `setupDoubleClick).

If a method is fired from the second element that has the custom attribute on it, is `this.clickWhen` set (because the first instance has set this.clickWhen) or is it still undefined.

(I hope it is the second.)

Comment: Not sure if I understood you question, but as far as I know, a different instance of the custom attribute is provided for every element that implements it. So, they are indepent

Comment: I think that a custom component would be a better approach in your case. So, you can control all elements, sharing the same properties. What do you think?

Comment: @fabio luz - actually I don't want it to share.

Comment: hmm I didn't understand what do you want... Could you explain me again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are separate instances and they won't affect each other.